# Agrupar por mínimos y máximos una tabla en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un programa que lee un dataset acordado por fechas, quiero agrupar los días iguales y en columnas distintas poner sus valores máximos y mínimos respectivos de una columna en otra. Intenté hacer un groupby pero se me complica buscar una manera de buscar ambos valores mínimos y máximos a la vez y se me ocurrió que agregándolos en columnas distintas sería la manera óptima para hacerlo, gracias de antemano por su paciencia. No podré adjuntar un link al dataset por motivos de seguridad pero sí podré mostrar cómo se ve desplegado con el código actual:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import pandas as pd

def leaflet_plot_stations(binsize, hashid):

    df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinSize_d{}.csv'.format(binsize))

    station_locations_by_hash = df[df['hash'] == hashid]

    lons = station_locations_by_hash['LONGITUDE'].tolist()
    lats = station_locations_by_hash['LATITUDE'].tolist()

    plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

    plt.scatter(lons, lats, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)
    
    #---my code---
    #1. Read the documentation and familiarize yourself with the dataset, then write some python code which returns a line graph 
    #of the record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014. The area between the record 
    #high and record low temperatures for each day should be shaded.
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
    df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
    
    df2[(df2['Date'] > '2005-01-01') & (df2['Date'] < '2014-12-31')]
    #sorting by date to make the data reading easier
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Date")
    
    #groupyingby the min and max
    #df2['Min'] = df2.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].min().reset_index()
    
    
    return df2

leaflet_plot_stations(400,'fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89')
```

[image: Tabla con los resultados por el momento]

Comment: Buen día, no es necesario que agregues el URL para descargar toda la información pero, ¿Puedes agregar los datos que tienes en tu imagen en formato de texto para que podamos copiarlos y utilizarlos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Para obtener el valor mínimo y máximo por día en una sola línea de código puedes utilizar el método `agg()` ([Documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)) que te permite agregar columnas

Primero puedes agrupar el `dataframe` por fecha para que tengas una única entrada de mínimo y máximo por cada fecha

A ese grupo le agregamos las columnas "TMIN" y "TMAX" (Puedes renombrarlas si necesitas) y le indicamos a cada columna la operación que debe hacer al elemento del grupo (En este caso mínimo o máximo de forma correspondiente)

Todo junto en una línea de código quedaría así:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg(TMIN = ('Data_Value', 'min'), TMAX = ('Data_Value', 'max'))
```

Por cierto, es mejor que siempre agregues un ejemplo de los datos que tienes en formato de texto, eso permite a que la persona que te va ayudar copiar y pegar la información, si agregas una imagen entonces es necesario hacer todo manualmente (Dato por dato) y en muchas ocasiones eso hace que las preguntas sean ignoradas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia.